# Связанные данные из связанной таблицы

Tags: ms-access

Есть три последовательно связанные таблицы: Туристы (один-к-одному) Информация о туристах (многие-к-одному) Туры. Я использую DataGridview1 чтобы отобразить список туристов. Datagridview2 я использую чтобы вывести туда связанные данные из DatagridView2: [ТуристыИнформацияОТуристахBindingSource]. в DataGridview3 я хочу отобразить связанные данные из того, что есть на данный момент в в DataGridview2, что то типа [ТуристыИнформацияОТуристахТурыBindingSource]. Где взять эту третью связь?

Comment: Три таблицы - максимум две связи (или схема запросто становится потенциально несовместной). Так что искать третью связь можно даже не начинать. То же относится и к гридам - три грида могут суммарно иметь только две связи.

Comment: Конечно они будут две связи иметь. Только мне нужно чтобы во втором гриде отображались связанные данные из первой, а в третьей - из второй